# Java Compiler Hangs

Tags: java, ant, compilation, javac, freeze

This question relates to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115597/use-of-java-generics-could-be-hanging-the-compiler); I am specifically asking here for help on how I can get more output rather than expanding on the earlier question. I am trying to compile my Java project form an Ubuntu 10.4 installation on an NTFS file system of my laptop configured to normally start in Win XP.

My Java version is:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The java compiler version is:

```
javac 1.6.0_24
```

In the following directory of my Java project:

```
~/NetBeansProjects/CliqueSpace/trunk/CliqueSpace
```

I enter the following command to compile my project:

```
ant -v clean jar
```

This is the last line of output. It corresponds to the final listed module of my project.

```
[javac]     /home/owen/NetBeansProjects/CliqueSpace/trunk/CliqueSpace/src/cliquespace/core/exception/cliquespace/undisclosed/identifier/UndisclosedIdentifier_FactoryNotGiven.java
```

The compiler appears to hang after "compiling" this last module of my project library. Hence, I don't think there's a problem with the compilation step. But I don't know for sure.

Question: How do I find out what is going on? Is there any debugging information that javac will give me? Is it something to do with the next step in the build script?

I don't know what is going on, and as I have never seen this problem before, I don't know what to do to find out.

I'm stumped. Any constructive suggestions and hints are most welcome.

Thanks.

Edit: I feel confident that the hang is happening in the javac compiler. The compiler shows all syntax errors after the line shown above is displayed; I now understand that the line above is output by ant in verbose mode as a note to the developer before the script starts the compiler. Although I still haven't yet tracked down the source of the problem causing the hang, I think I'm on to a strong lead... I may disclose something in my earlier question on Java generics discussing the solution if my lead turns out.

Comment: The first thing to do is to probably isolate the problem.  Run `javac` on that file by hand, in order to eliminate Ant as the problem.  (Then you can simplify your question as well ;))

Comment: Also, you could try running `top` in another console window to see what's actually using CPU time when things hang.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for the hints, I'll give them a go and get back if I need to. Sorry if I have made the question seem complicated; these questions are always a balance between brevity and completeness.

Comment: The question isn't overly-complicated (although I would probably put all the version info in a footnote or something).

Comment: I think you should jstack the Java process to watch the thread dump, may be you can figure something out.

Comment: @GavinXiong Thanks for the suggestion, though I'm happy enough now to move back to the problem described in my earlier question. :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe I have found an adequate answer to this question. I have have re-edited the question and put a suggestion in there.