# Java generic class with two related types

Tags: java, generics

What I want to do is the following:

```
public class DBManager<T extends Type , Q extends Query>{
    T create(T t);
    Collection<T> read(Q query);
    T update(T t);
}
```

However, I only want instantiations of this class where T and Q are related. For instance, if T is AppleType, then I want Q to be AppleQuery and not PearQuery.

Is there a way to do this, or produce a similar behavior?

I tried `Q extends T & Query`, but that isn't allowed.

Comment: Even if you could do that, I don't think you'd get very far on the implementation side of things.

Comment: Why not? It's absolutely possible that you're correct, but I haven't worked with generics in Java before, and I'm not immediately seeing the reason.

Comment: How much control do you have over Type and Query? If they are from your library you could wrap valid pairs in a "endorsed type" object.

Comment: Are Type and Query your own classes?  If so, can you share the details of each?

Comment: What is the relationship (if any) between the `Type` and `Query` classes?

Comment: @MrZarq To do anything useful in `DBManager` that requires a relationship with the types isn't going to be possible without specialising the code for the particular types. IYSWIM.

Comment: Yes, they're both my own classes. I don't think their content is all that important. They're only there so I could work with generic types but still have a say in what instantiations they create. I don't want them to be able to create a DBManager<HashMap> for instance.

Comment: @AndrewWhite, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Dolda2000's answer is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that unless the types themselves have some kind of relation in the type system.

Since I don't know exactly what you want to do, it's hard to recommend something with precision, but it sounds like you might want to do something like this:

```
public abstract class Type {
    ...
}

public class AppleType extends Type {
    ...
}

public abstract class Query<T extends Type> {
    public abstract T doQuery(); /* Or so? */
}

public class AppleQuery extends Query<AppleType> {
    public AppleType doQuery() {...}
}
```

With such a formal relation from `Query` to `Type`, you could then define your `DBManager` as such:

```
public class DBManager<T extends Type, Q extends Query<T>> {
    T read(Q id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Q` is not used in return types, you don't need it. Simply

```
interface DbManager<T extends Type>

    T read(Query<? extends T> query)
```

where

```
interface Type

interface Query<T extends Type>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make everything generic:

```
public class Type<Q extends Query<? extends Type<Q>>
public class Query<T extends Type<? extends Query<T>>

public class DBManager<T extends Type<Q> , Q extends Query<T>>
```

Comment: You probable want `public class Type<T extends Type<T, Q>, Q extends Query<Q, T>>`, etc., to be useful.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: Yes; I was thinking of suggesting that.  I'm pretty sure I went through this whole rigmarole in a recent SO answer, but I can't find it.

Comment: Well here's an example of the same kind of rigmarole: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423047/cyclical-generics-try-2

Answer (score 0):

There isn't multiple inheritance in Java. Why not just to do this?

```
public class Generic{
 // Generic atributes and methods.
}

public class ClassA extends Generic{
 // ClassA atributes and methods overwriting, if need it, the extended methods from Generic class.
}

public class ClassB extends Generic{
 // ClassB atributes and methods overwriting, if need it, the extended methods from Generic class.
}

... // You can instantiate so many classes as you need. You can use the factory pattern.
```